# Sub Menu items not able to render in Navigation

Tags: html, css

```css
.header{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  list-style-type: none;
  
}

.header .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;    
  border: none;
  color: #111;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  margin: 0;
  background: inherit;
}

.header:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #00b5cc;
}


.dropdown-content {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content li a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content li a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.header:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.drop-button {
  font-size: 16px;    
  border: none;
  color: #111;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  margin: 0;
  background: inherit;
}

.sub-menu{
  list-style-type: none;
  display:none;
}

.dropdown-content:hover .submenu{
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="header">
<li>
    <a class="dropbtn ">
    Apparel
    </a>  
    <ul class="dropdown-content">
    <li>
         <a>Girls
             <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li><a>Shoes</a></li>
         <li><a>Pants</a></li>
         <li><a>Skirts</a></li>
         <li><a>Tops</a></li>
         </ul>
         </a>
         </li>
   </ul>
       
</li> 
</ul>
```

I'm new to css and want to create a navigation bar.When I click on the Apparel section, the Girl section comes. But when I click on the girl section the sub items are not displayed.I want to display the menu items when I hover on Girl section Can someone please help me on this. I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: move them out of the girls anchor, they just need to be nested in the li (and nested anchors is invalid code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget dashed into submenu class now .sub-menu also forget display: block; Please Try following Code for good design.

```css
.header{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  list-style-type: none;      
}
.header ul {
  padding: 0;
}
.header .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;    
  border: none;
  color: #111;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  margin: 0;
  background: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
}
.header:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #00b5cc;
}
.dropdown-content {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content li a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content li a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.header:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.drop-button {
  font-size: 16px;    
  border: none;
  color: #111;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  margin: 0;
  background: inherit;
}
.sub-menu{
  list-style-type: none;
  display:none;
}
.dropdown-content:hover .sub-menu{
 background-color: red;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="header">
  <li>
    <a class="dropbtn ">Apparel</a>  
    <ul class="dropdown-content">
      <li>
        <a>Girls</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a>Shoes</a></li>
            <li><a>Pants</a></li>
            <li><a>Skirts</a></li>
            <li><a>Tops</a></li>
          </ul>            
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: some changes for good design you can more help please drop comments

Answer (score 1):

Please Try This Code

```
.header{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  list-style-type: none;

}

.header .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;    
  border: none;
  color: #111;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  margin: 0;
  background: inherit;
}

.header:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #00b5cc;
}


.dropdown-content {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content li a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content li a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.header:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.drop-button {
  font-size: 16px;    
  border: none;
  color: #111;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  margin: 0;
  background: inherit;
}

.sub-menu{
  list-style-type: none;
  display:none;
}

.dropdown-content:hover .submenu{
 background-color: red;
}
.dropdown-content li:hover .sub-menu { display: block; }
```

HTML:-

```
<ul class="header">
<li>
    <a class="dropbtn ">
    Apparel
    </a>  
    <ul class="dropdown-content">
    <li>
         <a>Girls</a>
             <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li><a>Shoes</a></li>
         <li><a>Pants</a></li>
         <li><a>Skirts</a></li>
         <li><a>Tops</a></li>
         </ul>

         </li>
   </ul>

</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: please explain what you have done and do not just do a code paste with try this

Comment: I'm trying and let you immediately